# Format table rows based on the value in specfic column changing in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with an employee appearing in the first column multiple times, I'd like to colour all rows as the employee name changes. Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve -

[image: Table Formatting]

I use the following conditional formatting formula for colouring every other row (if there is data) in a different table when I know the data will be changing every row. Is there something similar I can use to only change the colour if the item in the first column changes?

`=AND($A2<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a helper column as well - but calculating the "ID" of the employee.
Formula in `C2`

`=IF(A2<>A1,SUM(C1,1),C1)`

[image]

Then you can use the same logic as you showed us in your question:  `=MOD($C2,2)=0` as your format condition.

Comment: My only issue with this is that one name could end up with two different IDs if they weren't grouped together. Not a problem if it is only going to be used for this formatting. But it could be a bit confusing.

Comment: @Gravitate that's right - but I think it doesn't matter as the helper column isn't used as ID-column. And if so - yes: it then should sorted by employees name

Answer (score 2):

I would use a helper column which checks whether the name in the current row is different to the previous one or not. Then use this column in a simple conditional formatting.

```
=IF(B4<>B5,1-SUM(A4),SUM(A4))
```

[image]